# Odd Java issue: can find one file with short filepath but cannot find another

Tags: java, file

I'm working on a Java Swing application where I am reading in multiple graphic files to populate a tile based map editor.

I create these tile view objects of mine through the use of a class called TileSet which essentially breaks down my images into individual files.  The code itself works, but I am having an issue with my filepaths that has got me scratching my head.  Here is what's going on,

```
TileSelector ts = new TileSelector(new TileSet("src\\resources\\minecraft.png"));

MapView mapView = new MapView(new TileSet("src\\resources\\mapviewdefault.png"));
```

For some reason, my TileSelector accepts the format in which I wrote the directory to the image it will use, but MapView throws an IOException (File not found!).  Both files are within this directory, the only difference I can really think of is that one image is vastly larger than the other, where the smallest is loading up no issues.  If I go and put the full directory to the larger image it works, but since I'm writing this program for a school project which will be given to a sponsor, I cannot keep this format as the final way I deliver the package.

Any ideas?

Also, here is the code for my TileSet, where the issue is happening according to my stack trace...

```
private void createTileSet(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (!file.exists())
            throw new IOException("File not found...");

        image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));

        numTilesWidth = image.getWidth() /tileWidth; //Set how many tiles on the X axis there are
        numTilesHeight = image.getHeight() / tileHeight; //Set how many tiles on the Y axis there are
        numTiles = numTilesHeight * numTilesWidth;

        for (int h = 0; h < numTilesHeight; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < numTilesWidth; w++) {
                imagesList.add(image.getSubimage(w * tileWidth, h * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException catch: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `src` path will NOT exist at run time (when the application is built and packaged) and you should never reference it from within your code.  The resources can't within the `resources` directory will not be accessible as a normal `File` on the disk, because they aren't, they will typically be entries within the jar file.

Instead, you need to use `Class#getResource` to locate a load the resources...something like...

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fileName));
```

And you should call it using something like...

```
TileSelector ts = new TileSelector(new TileSet("/resources/minecraft.png"));
MapView mapView = new MapView(new TileSet("/resources/mapviewdefault.png"));
```

You should avoid using `\\` in your code, as it is not cross platform compatible, you can use `/` generally, if you really want to, use `File.separator` instead